# "Access is denied for the user:<>" Tridion Powershell Module

Tags: 2013-sp1, powershell

I am trying to install/configure the Tridion Powershell Module for coreservice API calls to our CMA running Tridion 2013 SP1 -- environment is configured and working correctly end to end including Content Porter-- I have successfully imported and installed the Tridion-CoreService module into Powershell.  I am able to successfully connect to the CMA server from my client and use 3 of the supplied commands with no issues: (`Get-TridionCoreServiceClient`, `Get-TridionCoreServiceSettings`, and `Set-TridionCoreServiceSettings`)

However, when attempting to use the other provided commands(`Get-TridionItem`, `Get-TridionUser`, etc.) I receive the following error.

```
PS C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\Installation> Get-TridionUser
Exception calling "GetCurrentUser" with "0" argument(s): "Access is denied for the user <domain\username>."
```

Windows Event Viewer throws the error:

```
Access is denied for the user <domain\username>.


Component: Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService
Errorcode: 770
User: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE

StackTrace Information Details:
at Tridion.ContentManager.Security.AuthorizationManager.LoadAccessToken(String userName, IEnumerable`1 mappedGroupUris, IEnumerable`1 claimSets)
at Tridion.ContentManager.Session..ctor(IEnumerable`1 claimSets)
at Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.CoreServiceBase.get_CurrentSession()
at Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.CoreServiceBase.IsExistingObject(String id)
at SyncInvokeIsExistingObject(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
at Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.CoreServiceInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc)
at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
```

I am confused as to why I can connect and create a valid session (deduced from my successful attempts to use the commands I mentioned above), but I am denied access by the other commands.

Any help / suggestions is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you list which version of the module that you are using? You can find that by typing: `(Get-Module Tridion-CoreService).Version.ToString()`

Comment: @ Peter Kjaer -- Version # is 2.0.2.0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Being able to create a client and connect is not the same as trying to perform an action that requires permissions. The message you are seeing is coming from Tridion: it's telling you that it does not recognise your user as a 'trustee'. I see that you have chosen to say `<domain\username>` rather than giving the actual value, but is the real value an account that you expect to have Tridion access? You should be able to go in to the Administration section in the Tridion GUI and see the list of users. Can you find this identity listed there? If so, does it have right/permissions to access anything? Answering these questions should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks @Dominic Cronin for your response. I am a "Trustee" in Tridion, with Admin rights. The account I am using is the same for Content Explorer, Content Porter, IIS (which has this user as an Impersonation User), and CMA server.
`Get-TridionCoreServiceSettings` returns a "UserName" identical to the user stored in Tridion. I am incorrect assuming cmd 'Set-TridionCoreServiceSettings' requires permissions? If I modify from default, then 'Get' cmd verifies settings were indeed updated.

Comment: But does the access denied message reference the same account?

Comment: Dominic is correct in saying that those working commands don't actually contact Tridion. They just configure the module. So you can't deduce much from them working, except that the module is apparently installed correctly.

Comment: I see your point @Dominic, after looking at the way the users are listed in Tridion, I see the error I receive is including domain <domain\username>, instead of only <username>.  I noticed when I open Content Porter the autofilled username includes my domain also, however this doesn't affect my ability to connect. That is where I am confused. I suppose Powershell is passing my domain as part of the credentials while Tridion is looking for only the username.  But why do those credentials work fine in Content Porter (which is connecting to Import/Export service)? Thanks again for your help!

Comment: A workaround would be to add yourself as a second trustee, with just the username

Comment: Are you using LDAP or a Single Sign-On solution? Or just Windows Authentication?

Comment: @Dominic -- Used your workaround and can now access CoreService through Powershell -- added myself a second time with username matching exactly the username given in the error message -- Thanks! Using LDAP for Tridion access -- Powershell call was appending "LDAP" to the my credentials which was causing the issue.  Still not sure why all other Tridion related services (CMA, Import/Export Service etc.) work with my initial account?